# python multiprocessing concurrent.futures

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a code in python of AI optimization. Execution take about 20h on one CPU core.

That's why I try my best to use threading - but GIL destroyed this idea.

Currently, I see potential in `concurrent.futures` and `executor.map`

in the main file is `if __name__ == '__main__':`
then all configuration to optimization is set, and the optimization function is called.
in secound file inside function I have:

```
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        res = executor.map(goal_fcn.objective_function, p)
    #fp = initialmulti(p)
        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(res):
            fp = res
```

the problem is: function `goal_fcn.objective_function` is never called

python returned me a mistake `concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

and one other mistake which is not a real mistake, I have     `xopt, fopt = pso(goal_fcn.objective_function, lb, ub, ieqcons=[], f_ieqcons=None, args=(), kwargs={}, NameError: name 'lb' is not defined` but variable `lb` is defines and script without multiprocessing work fine

Comment: You can't really ask us to debug your code without seeing your code.  Python doesn't lie, so if it says `lb` is not defined, then it is not defined.

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By the way, the `map` method does not return anything (i.e. `Future` instances) that you can use with the `as_completed` method; for that you need to use method `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.